# Idiomatic translation for "In sum and substance?"

Tags: word-choice

Google translate gives me "In Summe und die Substanz?'

But is there a better, more idiomatic translation?

And is that "better" translation "im großen und ganzen?" (This more literally back translates to "by and large," or "on the whole.")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suggestions:

- im wesentlichen
- im Kern
- letztlich
- im großen und ganzen
- alles in allem
- in groben Zügen
- unter dem Strich *(colloquial, but retains the mathematical metaphor)*
- summa summarum *(a Latin phrase, sometimes used in elaborated language)*

As so often, it depends on context which is suitable.

The phrase proposed by Google Translate is probably incomprehensible to any German who does not recognize the English original in it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Ich benutze bewußt die alte Rechtschreibung, deshalb habe ich deine Bearbeitung rückgängig gemacht.