# Ist „in groben Zügen“ ein Regionalismus?

Tags: phrase, regional

Ich hatte in meiner Antwort zu [Idiomatic translation for "In sum and substance?"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7819) unter anderem die Wendung „**in groben Zügen**“ vorgeschlagen. Bislang hielt ich sie für standardsprachlich und allgemein verbreitet. In einem Kommentar wies aber ein Muttersprachler darauf hin, daß sie zumindest ihm unbekannt gewesen sei.

Der Duden führt diese Wendung und das ähnliche „**in großen Zügen**“ in einigen Artikeln auf, etwa als Synonym zu [rudimentär](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rudimentaer). Eine Anmerkung zur Verwendung gibt es dort nicht.

Ist „in groben Zügen“ nur in Teilen des deutschen Sprachraums verbreitet? Wenn ja, in welchen?

Comment: Hm. Also ich kenne die Formulierung in genau der Bedeutung und wäre nie auf die Idee gekommen, dass diese regional sein soll...

Comment: Ich denke, dass die Formulierung einfach nur selten genutzt wird und sie daher nicht jedem bekannt ist. Ich musste auch erst kurz überlegen, habe es selten gehört. Denke also nicht, dass es ein Regionalismus ist.

Comment: in den 5 NBL völlig geläufig

Comment: "in großen Zügen" ist noch unverständlicher, und ist [imho nur im Kontext etwas genießen](http://archiv.raid-rush.ws/t-820642.html) sinnvoll, also "in vollen Zügen", z.b. also "etwas vollends genießen".

Comment: Mir ist auch jetzt noch nicht klar, wie man "in groben/großen Zügen" sinnvoll in einen Satz einbaut, so dass es sowas wie "im großen und ganzen" bedeutet. Abgeleitet von "grob gesagt" würde ich es mit "in grob(ß)en Zügen gesprochen" versuchen, aber redensarten-index.de lehrt mich, dass man es mit schildern oder darlegen versuchen sollte. In groben Zügen geschildert, das klingt sinnfrei für mich. - Ich könnte mich dennoch anschließen, dass es kein Regionalismus ist, und ich es mit Sicherheit schon einmal in meinem Leben gehört habe - das ist aber doch zu lang, als dass ich mich erinnern könnte.

Comment: @Em1 Kannst Du nochmal in groben Zügen schildern, wo dein Problem mit der Formulierung ist?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Das klingt sogar vernünftig und ich hätte es auch verstanden - ohne vorherige Diskussion. Dennoch klingt's für mich fremd, wie beispielsweise eine schlechte Übersetzung von [in broad strokes](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+broad+strokes). Hättest du von "großen Zügen" gesprochen, hätte ich aber auch noch einen Tippfehler erkannt. Weil "grob" ergibt mehr Sinn als "groß". (Vgl. "groß gesagt", äh, "grob gesagt")

Comment: *In großen Zügen* habe ich auch noch nie gehört. In groben Zügen ist für mich eine bekannte, stehende Redewendung.

Comment: Ist ein Regionalismus und nur auf Bahnhöfen gebräuchlich. ;) Gemeint ist der Regionalexpress, da liegt immer so viel Dreck rum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das [Wortschatz-Portal](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/) der Universität Leipzig führt derzeit 114 Belege für die Wendung **in groben Zügen** auf, die aus Onlineangeboten von Zeitungen und Fernsehsendern stammen und mehr oder weniger das ganze Sprachgebiet abdecken:

- Deutschland

  - Nordwest: Leer, Rotenburg (Wümme), Osnabrück, Hameln
  - Nordost: Berlin
  - Mittelwest: Marburg, Fulda, Frankfurt
  - Mittelost: Halle
  - Südwest: Stuttgart, Heidenheim, Reutlingen, Tübingen, Oberndorf
  - Südost: Ingolstadt, München, Passau
- Schweiz: Biel, Bern, Aarau, Zürich, Brig
- Österreich: Salzburg, Wien
- Namibia, Vatikan, Baltikum

(Die Orte beziehen sich auf den Sitz des Mediums; die Aufstellung ist nicht vollständig. Die Großregionen in Deutschland folgen der Einteilung im *Variantenwörterbuch des Deutschen*, 2004.)

Daraus kann man schließen, daß *in groben Zügen* nicht auf bestimmte Regionen beschränkt ist, sondern im ganzen deutschen Sprachgebiet bekannt ist und als ausreichend standardsprachlich für die Verwendung in Nachrichtentexten gilt.

---

Für die Wendung **in großen Zügen** bietet das Wortschatz-Portal sehr viel weniger Belege, nämlich nur 13 (eigentlich 14, aber in einem der Belege geht es um Tiere, die bei ihrer Wanderung *große Züge* bilden). Immerhin sind Deutschland, die Schweiz und Österreich (sowie Luxemburg und Namibia) vertreten, so daß man auch hier nicht von einem Regionalismus ausgehen muß.

Comment: Hahah. Du zählst nahezu jede Region Deutschlands auf, mit eigentlich nur einer Ausnahme. Und zwar genau die, wo ich lebe. - Schwein gehabt, immerhin war ich derjenige, der behauptet hat, das kennt kein Mensch.

Comment: @Em1: Das war Köln, richtig? [Suche beim Kölner Stadt-Anzeiger](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:ksta.de+%22in+groben+z%C3%BCgen%22), [Suche bei der Kölnischen Rundschau](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:rundschau-online.de+%22in+groben+z%C3%BCgen%22). Es ist zwar viel Agenturmaterial dabei, aber auch einiges von eigenen Lokalredakteuren. – Technisch gehört es übrigens zu _D-mittelwest_.

Answer (score 7):

Ich halte die Formulierung `in groben Zügen` absolut nicht für regional.

Es ist halt Hochdeutsch und heisst sowas wie `skizzieren` -> `to sketch`.

Ich kenne sie von klein auf, und bilde mir ein sie auch noch regelmässig zu hören/lesen.

---

`In grossen Zügen` dagegen fahre ich allenfalls durch die Gegend... ;-) - will sagen ist mir nun gar nicht geläufig.